# Is sso used in any other standard library containers other than std::string?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, c++14

SSO (small/short string optimization) can be used for `std::string`. But is it allowed to be used in other standard library containers (e.g. `std::vector`)? Does the answer depend on whether or not the template parameters of the containers are builtin types or user-defined types?

Comment: You really can't do this generically.  `std::string` knows it is storing `char`'s so it can be built to take advantage of this.  In something like a vector could have a type where a single element is larger the a buffer it could have.

Comment: `std::vector` implementation cannot employ small buffer optumization, since `swap` would invalidate iterators, which is forbidden by the Standard.

Comment: oh ok, got it, thank you for the information, @NathanOliver :)

Comment: There's another problem with using something like SSO with `vector`: you can't meet exception safety requirements if (for example) copying or moving an item might throw. `string` just says you can't instantiate it over a type that might throw, but `vector` can't do that.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think `std::function` can use "SSO" (small functor optimization?) to store its callable.

Comment: @BaummitAugen AFAIK, at least *gcc* implementation does it.

Comment: Of course, `std::function` isn't a container, so not sure if OP would let that count anyways.

Comment: std::function is required to use that optimization, at least to hold a function pointer.  More details in [ [func.wrap.func.con#4](http://eel.is/c++draft/func.wrap.func.con#4)]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The broader term is SBO - small buffer optimization. SSO is string specific.

Anyway, most of the other containers in the standard library cannot make use of SBO due to iterator invalidation rules. The standard guarantees that an iterator into a container remains valid through a move. That is:

```
std::vector<T> v = ...;
auto iter = v.begin(); // assume v is non-empty
std::vector<T> new_v = std::move(v);
foo(*iter); // *must* be okay
```

This guarantee is impossible to meet with SBO - since `iter` could point into the automatic storage of `vs`, which cannot magically transfer into `new_v`. `std::string` does not have this kind of guarantee, so it's okay.

On the other hand, something like `std::function<>` *can* (and typically does) implement SBO, since there is no such move guarantee. That's not really a container in the containers sense.

Comment: Do you know how it is possible that after move, iter remains valid ? I mean when you move all elements from v to the new location (here is new_v if it's big enough) then memory reserved on heap by v is deleted, so how it is possible that iter knows that it should point to the new location ?

Comment: @bladzio "then memory reserved on heap by `v` is deleted" It is not deleted. Its ownership is transfered to `new_v`. The memory that `new_v` had owned is the one that's deleted.